# Podman container not able communicate through their name

Tags: networking, dns, podman

I am facing the issue with podman DNS part.
I was not able to communicate the two podman container through their name in the same podman network.
But that two container are able to communicate through their IP's.
Podman Version-4.2.0
OS version - RHEL 8.7

we give the hostname of container same as container name but its still not working.